# Auto-complete on NSComboBoxCell via Binding in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, binding, nstableview

I don't know whether I have set this up incorrectly or not, but what I have done makes sense to me.

I have an NSTableView with two columns in it - a properties column on the left and a values column on the right. The values column contains NSComboBoxCells which are to be (dynamically) pre-populated with values relevant to the property in the left column.

The table is bound to an NSArrayController which references an array of objects. The object referenced has a number of properties defined, including one for the properties column (the property is called "name"), a value for the values column (called "value"), and a possibleValues property which returns the NSArray of available values dependent on the property.

This is all working correctly as long as the values cells are not being edited. As soon as they are edited, the drop-down of possible values is empty.

Having searched around, I found suggestions that the auto-complete checkbox should be checked for the Combo Box Cell, but checking it does not alter behaviour. I want the user to be able to tab from one table cell to the next, remaining in edit mode, and being able to make use of a pre-populated list of possible values.

On the object containing the data to be displayed in the table, I have declared the keyPathsForValuesAffecting... method too as such:

```
+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingPossibleValues
{
    return [NSSet setWithObject:@"name"];
}
```

The detailed bindings are as such:

**Property** column is bound to arrayController

Value binding:

```
    Controller Key: arrangedObjects
    Model Key Path: name
```

**Value** column is bound to the same arrayController

Content binding:

```
    Controller Key: arrangedObjects
    Model Key Path: possibleValues
```

Value binding:

```
    Controller Key: arrangedObjects
    Model Key Path: value
```

**NSComboBoxCell** is not bound to anything. I have tried binding the content of the cell to the same as the value binding for the value column, but I get a list of objects - not the list of strings I create.

The header file for the object stored in the NSMutableArray which is bound to the NSArrayController basically looks something like:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TableProperty : NSObject {
    NSString *name;
    NSString *value;
}

@property (readwrite, strong) NSString *name;
@property (readwrite, strong) NSString *value;
@property (readonly, assign) NSArray *possibleValues;

@end
```

The name and value properties are synthesised. The possibleValues property is a method which returns an array of NSString objects - the contents of which depend on the value of name.

I have put a break-point in the possibleValues method, which gets hit (twice) when the edit mode is started on the cell (and the correct NSArray is returned - both times). Once in edit mode, hitting the DOWN button on the keyboard pops up an empty box - this is the one which I would like to have populated with values. If the selection arrows to the right of the cell are clicked with the mouse, I have my list of correct values.

It is not possible for me to use a view-based table, as I need this application to function on Snow Leopard machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NSComboBoxCell inherits auto completion functionality from NSTextFieldCell which requires you to supply a datasource. There is no binding that will implement the functionality for you. The reason for this is that the control is working with NSStrings and your list can have multiple items with the same string representation.

Comment: I am afraid I don't really understand what you are saying. Firstly: 

_The contentValues binding of NSComboBoxCell controls the title properties of the item list._ - I am not binding to the NSComboBoxCell - I am binding to the column containing the cells. In a view-based table I would expect to bind to individual views, however my understanding is that in my case you would bind to the column.

_If you don't bind to `content` without binding to `contentValues`..._ - Do you mean _If you **do**..._

Binding to contentValues on the column makes no difference to the behaviour as described above.

Comment: You are right, I had that worded incorrectly. Editing answer.

Comment: Thank you for your continued replies (and edits). I am not sure whether I have been unclear in my original post or whether you have misunderstood. I am not seeing weird objects in the list and binding to `possibleValues.self` results in a binding error (`[<__NSArrayM 0x109ae4b50> addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] is not supported. Key path: self`). The issue I have is that in edit mode I don't have any values in the drop down. In standard mode, the bindings are working perfectly and my drop-downs are populated.

Comment: Do you have "Autocompletes" checked in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes (as detailed in the original post):
_I found suggestions that the auto-complete checkbox should be checked for the Combo Box Cell, but checking it does not alter behaviour._

Comment: Do you have "Uses Datasource" checked?

Comment: I don't. My understanding was that with that checked the contents of the list would have to be populated programatically and not through binding. Correct me if I am wrong. When I did check it, I was required to add all the manual functions to the datasource class. Given that out of edit mode the list is correctly populated through binding, I considered it not worth trying.

Comment: The string completion cannot be done through bindings. Updated answer.

Comment: OK. Thanks. When I get the chance I will have a look and see whether I can get the list populated programatically using a datasource.

Comment: Thanks - finally it is working - although it's a real shame it cannot be done through binding. The only thing which is not working now is when in edit mode, I can use the cursor keys to change selection on the combo box cell values, but hitting ENTER does not select a value and ends the edit session of the cell. Do you know why this may be? The NSTableView and NSComboBoxCell both use the same class as their data sources, but I can't imagine that's the problem.

Comment: If you didn't implement `comboBoxCell:indexOfItemWithStringValue:` in your datasource that might cause it.

Comment: The function has been implemented and is called (once) when the combo box is dropped down. The value of the cell is still not updated when in edit mode and the ENTER key hit following a selection of an item in the drop-down list though.